# Why is this binary scan type specifier escaped with a backslash?

Tags: tcl

I am updating a project with about a zillion unit tests, so I figured this was a good time to learn Tcl and convert all those tests to Tcl scripts, so that the next time I have to do this, it will be much easier to add new tests. In addition to reading my 2 new books on Tcl, I'm looking over existing scripts online and I ran across this one:

```
proc do_bincmp_test {testname got expect} {
  binary scan $expect \c* expectvals
  binary scan $got \c* gotvals
  do_test $testname [list set dummy $gotvals] $expectvals
}
```

and I'm trying to figure out why the type specifier is escaped with a backslash. I wrote this script and ran it:

```
set expect {Hello World}
binary scan $expect \c* expectvals
puts $expectvals
binary scan $expect c* expectvals
puts $expectvals

=>72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100
=>72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100
```

I can't find *anything* in the literature (either online or in the 2 books I have) about escaping type specifiers, just the standard policy that if an escaped character is not one of the special characters that require escaping, the literal
character is used.

So, I figure there are 3 possibilities:

- The backslash is an artifact from a much earlier version of Tcl that doesn't do anything now.
- The backslash is an ordinary run-of-the-mill brain fart that is harmless.
- The backslash is some sort of devilish Tcl subtlety that I am completely overlooking.

I would really like to know which one it is.

I am using Tcl 8.6.7 from IronTcl

Comment: Could also be a typo.

Comment: I suppose, but the same typo on both lines? That would lean more toward "brain-fart" I think.

Comment: When in doubt, go to [the rules](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M16) -- in this case `\c` is not special so Tcl merely drops the backslash. Perhaps the original author didn't understand the meaning.

Comment: @glennjackman: I know, that's the standard policy I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the Tcl(n) manual page](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) (the specification of the Tcl language core itself), `\c` has no special meaning (without other escaping) as it is not explicitly listed as one of the backslash-substitution sequences, and so that's equivalent to a plain `c` character. My guess is that it was put in there out of misunderstanding or as a typo that didn't trigger an error.

It also has no cost apart from slightly more expensive initial parsing. By the time the value hits Tcl's bytecode, that backslash is already gone.

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured. I wasn't sure if, in an older version of Tcl, it did something like `$cmd\(args)` to turn off array indexing (I think) as mentioned in "Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk" [Welch, et. al.] I still haven't got quite far enough to understand exactly what they're talking about there.

Comment: Ad "turn off array indexing": Unlikely in that form, you would to protect the variable name including a backslash additionally using curly braces `${cmds\(args\)}` to achieve this effect (i.e. a variable named `cmds\(args\)` (not the literal backslash therein!) rather than a variable `args` prefix-bundled into a Tcl array named `cmds` or similar. W/o curly braces, a `\\` just ends the variable name.

Comment: We tend to recommend avoiding complicated trickery with quoting for stuff like that; it's usually flaky (i.e., breaks with certain inputs) and confusing/hard to read.